# Gradle Build in Android Studio Showing 3 compilation errors

Tags: android, build.gradle

I tried to compile my app but gradle build finishes with the following errors.

```
 Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
                Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
                  Error:1 error; aborting
                 Error:Execution failed for task 
                 ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
                  ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
             > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    
              java.lang.RuntimeException: 
               com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
                org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command   
               'C:\Program             Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' 
                       finished with non-zero exit value 1
             :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

Please tell me how I can get rid of them.

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: as the guy above me said, please post your gradle build file here so we have an idea what is wrong.

Comment: There are no clearer answers than what is below without the build.gradle on application level

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Additionally, you might want to consider using MultiDex to prevent those problems in the future: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

**ALSO**

Remember to update java to the newest version! Android Studio 2.0 and newer versions of android require java 1.8 or higher

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the following:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Since, one of your dependencies may require it.